# Python: Sending a hex value to an external device over TCP or UDP

Tags: python, tcp, struct, hex, pack

Ok,
  I hope that I can explain what I am trying to do.  I have an external device that accepts 4 byte commands with a checksum value.  I need to send these to an external ethernet to serial interface and then read back the data recevied from the device.  So far I can do this from a python script to a python script.  WHere I am running into a problem is when sending the data to the device.  I have tried using b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00' format, I have tried byte arrays and so on.  I have wiresharked the data going out and see the data payload looking correct.  But, I am not getting a response to the query I am sending.

```
import struct
import sys
import string
import select
import time
import binascii
import SocketServer

port = 8010
# region Read Codes

getSerial = [0x26, 0x0A, 0x00, 0xF0]

#Communication utilities

class CommUtilities():

    #Convert to bytearray
    def hexit2(self, inp):
        return bytearray(inp)

    def calculateChecksum(self, buf):
        checksum = 0x5A #Starting checksum
        #For each byte, bitwise XOR it with our checksum
        for b in buf:
            checksum ^= b
        return checksum

    #Append the one byte checksum to a command
    #returns the complete byte array
    def appendChecksum(self, buff):
        buff.append(self.calculateChecksum(buff))
        return buff

class TCPHandler():

    """ Notes here.... TCP Handler """

    def recv_timeout(self, the_socket, timeout=2):
         total_data=[]
         data=''
         begin=time.time()
         while l:
             #if you got some data, then break after wait a sec
             if total_data and time.time()-begin>timeout:
                 break
             #if you got not data at all, wait a little longer
             elif time.time()-begin>timeout*2:
                 break
             try:
                 data=the_socket.recv(1024)
                 if data:
                     total_data.append(data)
                     begin=time.time()
                 else:
                     time.sleep(0.1)
             except:
                 pass
         return ''.join(total_data)

def start_server_receive(host):

        sock=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM)
        sock.setsockopt(SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
        sock.bind(('0.0.0.0', port))
        sock.listen(5)
        print 'started on',port
        while True:
            host = '0.0.0.0'
            newsock,host=sock.accept()
            print 'connected'
            result= self.recv_timeout(newsock)
            print 'got', result
        sock.close()
        return result

def send_server(data, host):
        sock=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM)
        sock.setsockopt(SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
        sock.connect((host, port))

        print data
        #Is this strip needed?  Tried both with and without....
        data = data.strip()

        sock.sendall(data)
        print 'Sent Data'
        sock.close()


def main():
    comm = CommUtilities()
    tcp = TCPHandler()

    host = "172.16.2.52"

    #get data to send
    data = comm.appendChecksum(getSerial)
    data = comm.hexit2(data)

    #Create a socket (SOCK_STREAM means a TCP socket)

    while True:
        try:
            #Connect to server and send data
            send_server(data, host)
            #Receive data from the server and shut down
            received = start_server_receive(host)
        finally:
            pass
        print "send:    {}".format(data)
        #print "received:{}".format(received)
        time.sleep(2)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

So any suggestions?  I have example code that works in C# (which I didn't write since I don't know C# well at all), but how would I import that into python or use it?  Otherwise I need a way to make the device respond...

Any and all suggestions would be appreciated.

Is it because I am not using struct.pack?  If that is it, then how would I create the struct.pack function to make this work?  I am not very well versed in the struct.pack method yet.

Comment: If I'm understanding you correctly, you looked with a packet sniffer and see the correct bytes being sent but no answer coming back.  Is that correct?  If that's the case we're unlikely to be able to help...

Comment: Yeah thats right, but I was wondering if maybe i was reading something wrong in the packet, or if there was a better way to form the packets?  I have seen a lot of people say use struct.pack but I am just to dunderheaded to understand that i think.  I know this is a long shot, but am beating my head against the wall with this one.